# Cancel a notification from browser that was created by a service worker

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if I can cancel a notification from a script running in a tab that was created by a service worker for that site?

This is what I have now:

- I use Firebase messaging to push a message to the service worker.
- If the site is not opened or in background, the service worker creates the notification.

Now, when the user opens the site without clicking the notification, I want to dismiss it. I have to do it from the site's javascript because it should only dismiss the notification when a specific action is performed. Do I need to send a message to the service worker or..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. From the client you have access to the service worker via ServiceWorkerRegistration and that has a method to get all notifications the SW registered.

See: [ServiceWorkerRegistration.getNotifications()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications)

There is another way but it involves more code: send a message (using `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage`) to the service worker, get the notifications (`self.registration.getNotifications()`) and then cancel them from there. This is how I solved the question and then found out about the first solution. This may still be useful if you need to have the service worker do other things, too, though. Also, it's kind of nice to cancel the notification in the same place it was created :)